# Substring a column in pandas

Tags: python, string, str-replace

I have a dataframe like this

| Index | Identifier |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 10769289.0 |
| 1 | 1082471174.0 |

The "Identifier column is a string column" and I need to remove the ".0"

I'm using the following code:

```
Dataframe["Identifier"] = Dataframe["Identifier"].replace(regex=['.0'],value='')
```

But I got this:

`IndexIdentifier0769289182471174`

As you can see it removed more than just the ".0". I also tried to use

```
Dataframe["Identifier"] = Dataframe["Identifier"].str.replace(".0", "")
```

but I got the same result.

Comment: Do all your identifiers end with ".0" ?
Strange. It looks like that a problem occured between the identifiers at the origin and those stored in the dataframe.
Do you have any way to clean before creating the dataframe ?

Comment: Anyway in case all your identifiers are unwantey suffixed by dot zero.
A simple solution would be to remove the last two characters.
`df["Identifier"] = df["Identifier"].map(lambda x: x[:-2])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot (`.`) in [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) or in **replace** can indicate `any` character. Therefore you have to **escape** the decimal point. Otherwise it will replace **any** character followed by a zero. Which in your case would mean that it would replace the `10` at the beginning of `10769289.0` and `1082471174.0`, as well as the `.0` at the end of each number. By escaping the decimal point, it will only look for the following: `.0`  - which is what you intended.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create the dataframe as per the example
Dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"Index": [0,1], "Identifier": ['10769289.0', '1082471174.0']})

# Replace the decimal and the zero at the end of each Identifier.
Dataframe["Identifier"] = Dataframe["Identifier"].str.replace("\.0", "")

# Print the dataframe
print(Dataframe)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   Index  Identifier
0      0    10769289
1      1  1082471174
```